# Why is the official Stack Exchange application not available for Android v2.3.6?

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I am using an Android phone with v2.3.6 (Gingerbread). It's very difficult to edit questions and answers from the default phone browser. When I looked for the official app for SO, I found that it does not support my current version of Android.

Can you release a version of the app for this version of Android?

Comment: Why original question edited in such a way which hide my feeling regarding question???? :-(

Comment: Wait you actually wanted SO to buy a new android for you?

Comment: @scrblnrd3 Yes, SO now has two choice, first make official app support for 2.3.6 or buy me new 4.0 or higher version android phone

Comment: Just a suppose, old Android means old smartphone, and it means end with excessive memory usage etc. I don't see reason why that app would have excessive memory usage, but it's hard to write in a sparing way if you're not used to.

Comment: @AnkushMadankar no, they have a third option-have you use it in a browser

Comment: @AnkushMadankar why should SO buy you a new phone?  I'm very curious as to why you think SO needs to do this just because your phone won't run their beta app.  The fact that you reference that you are an "Established User" in the original version gives me the impression you think that your rep somehow entitles you?  So if having 1000 rep gets you a new phone, what do the users with 100K rep get?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Macbook or windows PC, whatever they like to use :-)

Comment: FWIW Gingerbread was the last good version of Android OS. _Don't_ upgrade.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Jon Skeet got a unicorn painting at 200k rep. I got a mug, a tumbler and some generic SE swag at the same milestone. Gotta love inflation.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn So, I suppose to wait upto 200K :)

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps because Gingerbread represents 13.5% of the overall Android market and is shrinking all the time.

(source: [What percentage of devices have each of the Android versions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/4447/267))

[image: pie chart illustrating the market penetration of each version of Android]

There are quite a few changes between API level 10 and level 15. It's probably not worth the time and effort to try to make the app work without some of the things that have been added to the API in the last couple years.

Comment: I'm having flashbacks to IE6 here... ;)

Comment: O, so do you think 25% less percentage?? I am coming in it. I think API 10 support almost what SO site has.

Comment: I'm not a dev. I'm just speculating as to their reasons.

Comment: Infact not providing support to lower version of android loose 25% of user, isnt it?

Comment: No, it might loose 25% of the users that want to use a native application on andriod to visit stackoverflow.

Comment: (shrug) The Android app is not their main product. It's just an adjunct.

Comment: I find SO implement every thing in perfect way if it provided support for 25% of other user :-(

Answer (score 5):

They would have to make significant changes to the codebase and/or rewrite the application to work on a nearly 3-year old system which has a fairly low market share. It's like asking them to make it IE5, Netscape and [Iceweasel](http://www.geticeweasel.org/) compatible

Look [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Android_historical_version_distribution_-_vector.svg) for a nice graph of android operating systems by percent

And as for buying you a new phone... how about no

Perhaps, though, you could win some other Stack Swag, like t-shirts and mugs, if you win a contest

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested in one of the apps users published on [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app+android). I’m sure there are a few your phone supports.

That being said, I personally think the mobile view for StackExchange sites is already pretty good—at least for reading. And answering, commenting or editing on the phone is always a hassle anyway.